# Information on Databases and websites

Tags: javascript, database

So Im learning javacript and jquery right now. Im just wondering for using a database with a website what is the best method, or best database?

Im just going to be working on a website as part of my learning. Im going to make a fantasy football site. So there will be login information and i will need a database to store players and scores, etc. I think if I use javascript and HTML to build the site then connecting to a database requires java servlets, is this correct?

So can anyone tell me what is the usual way people use databases with websites? I think javascript should pretty much just be used for the front end. So what should take care of database retrieval? though if javascript just takes care of the front end, then it still needs access to the data returned from the database.

I was farting around on google without finding anything concrete so if anyone could tell me or point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Im just wondering for using a database with a website what is the best method, or best database?

Very broad. Lots of good options: [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/), [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), [Redis](http://www.redis.io), etc. The list goes on.

> I think if I use javascript and HTML to build the site then connecting to a database requires java servlets, is this correct?

Incorrect. You connect to a database on the back-end (for example, if your using a full-stack JavaScript environment, you might consider using the [Mongoose](http://www.mongoosejs.com) library to connect your [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org) server to your Mongo database.)

> I think javascript should pretty much just be used for the front end.

No. It can be used for the front-end, server, and database.

> then it still needs access to the data returned from the database.

Correct. Your front-end won't communicate directly with the database in 99.9999% of the cases. You'll query your server, and your server queries the database. If you want to take a more dynamic approach, you'll likely be using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to asynchronously query your server.

Comment: Cool, I look into some of them you mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: one thing actually. why use them databases ahead of just a standard MS SQL Server DB?

Comment: @discodowney, I haven't used MS SQL, so I can't speak to its advantages/disadvantages, but in general when deciding which database to use, it just depends on how it can be integrated with the other existing technologies within your application stack.

Comment: @discodowney, also, there's nothing necessarily more "standard" about a MS SQL database as compared to other databases.

Comment: yeah, that was a stupid thing to say. its standard for me cos its the only one i have used since college.

Comment: @discodowney, not stupid, but you just don't want to limit your options.